# Flex++ bad character error and more. new to flex

Tags: lex, flex-lexer, flex++

we are just getting started using flex to build a lexer for a project, but we cant figure out how to get it to work. I copy the example code given in tutorials and try to run flex++ with the tut file as its argument however I just receive an error each time. e.g.

**input file** (calc.l)

```
%name Scanner
%define IOSTREAM

DIGIT   [0-9]
DIGIT1  [1-9]

%%

"+"               { cout << "operator <" << yytext[0] << ">" << endl; }
"-"               { cout << "operator <" << yytext[0] << ">" << endl; }
"="               { cout << "operator <" << yytext[0] << ">" << endl; }
{DIGIT1}{DIGIT}*  { cout << "  number <" << yytext    << ">" << endl; }
.                 { cout << " UNKNOWN <" << yytext[0] << ">" << endl; }

%%

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Scanner scanner;
    scanner.yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

with this code i get

> flex++ calc.l
>       calc.l:1: bad character: %
>       calc.l:1: unknown error processing section 1
>       calc.l:1: unknown error processing section 1
>       calc.l:1: unknown error processing section 1
>       calc.l:2: unrecognised '%' directive

could anyone help me understand what im doing wrong here? cheers

Comment: Did you by chance get this from http://www.mario-konrad.ch/index.php?page=20024 ? I'm having the same problem although I've just this second downloaded it so I will look into it.

Comment: I'm getting the same error here.

Comment: I know this is a really old question... but I found at least one way to get this type of file to compile and run if you ever need it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You might try something like:

- adding `%{ ... %}` to the first couple of lines in your file
- adding `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` *(instead of trying to define Scanner)*
- adding `%option noyywrap` above the *rules* section
- using just `yylex()` *(instead of trying to call the method of a non-existant Scanner)*

---

With your example, it could look something like this:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
%}

DIGIT   [0-9]
DIGIT1  [1-9]

/* read only one input file */
%option noyywrap

%%
"+"               { cout << "operator <" << yytext[0] << ">" << endl; }
"-"               { cout << "operator <" << yytext[0] << ">" << endl; }
"="               { cout << "operator <" << yytext[0] << ">" << endl; }
{DIGIT1}{DIGIT}*  { cout << "  number <" << yytext    << ">" << endl; }
.                 { cout << " UNKNOWN <" << yytext[0] << ">" << endl; }
%%

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of flex++ you using?
I uses 'Function: fast lexical analyzer generator C/C++  V2.3.8-7 (flex++), based on 2.3.8 and modified by coetmeur@icdc.fr for c++' (-? option) and your cacl.c is processed perfectly..

For Win32, this version of Flex++/Bison++ is [here](http://www.kohsuke.org/flex++bison++/)